# Number System with 11/5 base

Tags: number-systems

I was given a question that says,

"Give illustrative example(s) of number(s) in number systems with base 20, 02, 11/5. Prove that such examples are valid by translating selected numbers to decimal number system and then back to the required one."

I understand how to do base 20 and 02 but I can't get 11/5 at all. I'm having trouble converting it to base 10 and back to base 11/5.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-number-base/

Comment: Is there any way you can provide an example. It still seems confusing. @Aretino